# A particular condition is being skipped in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to make a javascript price calculator that takes in values from a form consisting no text fields but only radio buttons and checkboxes. Here is my JavaScript:

```
service = 0;

var setPoint = function (elem) {
    var $e = $(elem);
    var points = $e.attr("data-points");
    switch ($e.attr("name")) {
        case 'group1':
            group1 = parseFloat(points);
        case 'group2':
            group2 = parseFloat(points);
        case 'group4':
            group4 = parseFloat(points);
        case 'group5':
            group5 = parseFloat(points);
        case 'services':
            if ($(elem).attr('checked1') == 'true') {
                $(elem).attr("checked1", "false");
                service = parseFloat(service) - parseFloat(points);
            } else {
                $(elem).attr("checked1", "true");
                service = parseFloat(service) + parseFloat(points);
            }
    }
}

var calculatePoints = function () {    
    var total;    
    var values = [group1, group2, group4, group5, service];

    values.map(function (value) {
        if (value == "" || value == undefined || value == NaN) {
            value = 0;
            return value;
        }
    });

    if (service == 0) {
        window.alert("At least one service needs to be selected!");
        console.log("Service = 0");
    } else if (service <= 20) {
        total = group1 + group2 + group4 + group5 + service;
    } else if (service > 20 && service <= 40) {
        total = group1 + group2 + group4 + group5 + (service * 0.8);
    } else total = group1 + group2 + group4 + group5 + (service * 0.7);

    console.log(total * 1000);

    return false;
}
```

But somehow, the conditional statement `if (service==0)` is not working at all!

I am calling the setPoints function using onclick method in my HTML upon each click on a form field and calculatePoints function using onsubmit. I have made sure that the page doesn't get refreshed when using onsubmit.

I dont know what is wrong with my code and why it is happening so an explaination along with your solutions would me much helpful. You can find a codepen with complete code here : http://codepen.io/anshap1719/pen/pNjepV

Comment: You've not really given enough information for anyone to help you.. However, assuming you call `setPoint()` first, passing the `services` element, then `service` will not be `0`. You need to debug this yourself and check the value of `service` at each stage of the logic flow

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry I just made the edit to explain how I am calling my functions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that the value is not coming out to be 0 but I cant understand why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to end each case with a break statement into the switch case.

```
switch ($e.attr("name")) {
    case 'group1':
        group1 = parseFloat(points);
        break;
    case 'group2':
        group2 = parseFloat(points);
        break;
    case 'group4':
        group4 = parseFloat(points);
        break;
    case 'group5':
        group5 = parseFloat(points);
        break;
    case 'services':
        if ($(elem).attr('checked1') == 'true') {
            $(elem).attr("checked1", "false");
            service = parseFloat(service) - parseFloat(points);
        } else {
            $(elem).attr("checked1", "true");
            service = parseFloat(service) + parseFloat(points);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Without a break your switch case doesn't work, it will jump to the last case or it won't work at all, is in this way by design @AnshulSanghi

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AnshulSanghi also, a switch case without break is a syntax error. I'm glad for being helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize your variables `group1` ... `group5` with **zeroes** as well as you did with `service` so if any of the radiobuttons is not chosed, not to get you console error, to be as follow:

```
service = group1 = group2 = group3 = group4 = group5 = 0;
```

Comment: Actually, I dont want to validate any other fields other than services. Only services field is required that's why I didn't do that. Also, if I initialize every variable, the value is changed only inside the function and outside the setPoints function, there value was still 0.

Comment: So you will get console error like this `group1 is not defined` and ofourse putting the missing `break`s after each case as @Sycraw mentioned.

Comment: Can't help it. Coz the value isnt changed outside if I initialize them. Do you know of any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if ($(elem).attr('checked1') === 'true') {
    // Code here, use triple === for conditional equality check
}
```

Comment: I think there was a separate issue, that the previous answer seems to have solved. Conditional equality checks in js should be === though. Have a nice day!

Comment: Just made the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Console for Errors, as it says group1 is not defined.
You have not defined the variables you have used in switch.

```
var service = 0, group1=0.0, group2=0.0, group4=0.0, group5=0.0;
```

This will give you the required output.

Comment: if I initialize every variable, the value is changed only inside the function and outside the setPoints function, their value was still 0. I dont want that. Do you know any workaround for that?